Error related to recaptcha in console in magento checkout
I am getting an error in the console of the checkout page and also not getting the recaptcha box on the checkout page.
I am having the Magento 2.4.6 p5 version. I can place an order if the configuration of the captcha is disabled. but when enabled, I get the validation message on the checkout page.
See the image below:- 

I have tried to disable the captcha modules but it is not giving any result, also tried to enable and disable the captcha from admin but the result I am getting is the same.
I am expecting to clear the error I am getting in console and remove the checkout validation error on placing an order.

Is this magento default re-captcha or third party extensions?

I am using Magento default re-captcha.

Then you can use the answer which I post.

I'm currently running into the same issue on my Magento 2.4.6-p5 instance. We're using a Hyva frontend. But since you're not using this it seems not related to that.

Hi @AmanMamdani this post solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78296964/recaptcha-en-js-uncaught-typeerror-qf-is-not-a-function Maybe you should take a look as well.

Thanks @kipzes for your feedback as it has helped me solve my problem.

To enable/disable reCaptcha for frontend forms:
Admin->Configuration->Stores->Customers->Customer Configuration->CAPCTHA->Forms

Disable frontend captcha from CLI :
php bin/magento config:set customer/captcha/enable 0


I've already disabled customer captcha, but this doesn't seem to solve the issue in my case.

after disable, you need to run all magento command like, upgrade, deploy etc and then need to check.

I am aware of that, but the error is on the development and production environment. This setting is already disabled for a long time (since we're using Hyva). We have this setting locked in our env.php
